# PIL.ImageOps.fit() gives AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python-imaging-library, attributeerror

i`m getting an error while trying to crop my photo using PIL.ImageOps.fit()

*its
This is my code:

```
import sys
from PIL import ImageOps, Image, ImageChops

import PIL


#user comand-line input validation
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    sys.exit("Amount of argumets is not corrent")

name, newName = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

splitedName, splitedNewName = name.split("."), newName.split(".")

formats =["jpg","jpeg","png"]
# print(splitedName[1],splitedNewName[1])
if splitedName[1] != splitedNewName[1] and  splitedName not in formats:
    sys.exit("Formats are not correct!")



#Photo processing

shirt = Image.open("shirt.png")
size = shirt.size
im2 = ImageOps.fit(name,size)

im2.paste(shirt,shirt)

im2.save(newName)
```

I`m getting an error which says that str doesn`t have attribute size:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lev/CS50/shirt/shirt.py", line 26, in <module>
    im2 = ImageOps.fit(name,size)
  File "/home/lev/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageOps.py", line 461, in fit
    bleed_pixels = (bleed * image.size[0], bleed * image.size[1])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ImageOps.fit()` with as first argument the name of the image (variable `name`), which is a string. If you look up the [documentation of ImageOps.fit()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html), you see that the first argument should be an image itself, not a filename.

Solution: change this line:

```
im2 = ImageOps.fit(name,size)
```

into:

```
im2 = ImageOps.fit(shirt,size)
```